# Calculating confidence interval in linear mixed effect model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, confidence-interval, conditional-probability

Consider a simple linear mixed effect model (LMM)
$$Y_{ij}=b_{i}+X_{ij}\beta+\epsilon_{ij},$$
where $b_i\sim N(0,\sigma_b^2)$, $\epsilon_{ij}\sim N(0,\sigma_e^2)$.
Typically, one can estimate $\sigma_b^2,\sigma_e^2$, then use the Hessian matrix to calculate the confidence interval of $\beta$.

I am thinking another way, can we first calculate $\hat{b}_i=E(b_i|\{Y_{ij},X_{ij}\})$ and $Y^{*}_{ij}=Y_{ij}-\hat{b}_i$. And then, we infer $\beta$ based on simple linear regression between $\{X_{ij}\}$ and $\{Y^{*}_{ij}\}$?

I think this estimate should be consistent since it is a natural estimation based on EM algorithm. But I am not sure about the validity of the confidence interval.